# JSDoc not found in Dockerfile RUN command but can be run from attached shell

Tags: bash, docker, shell

I currently have a PHP and JavaScript project in a Docker container and have written a shell script (generate-documentation.sh) to generate the documentation for the different sections of the project and place it in subdirectories of the /docs directory, this includes the `jsdoc` command, as well as `phpdoc` commands.

As part of my Dockerfile, I am installing JSDoc using

```
# Install NVM
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash \
# Setup NVM
  && export NVM_DIR="/root/.nvm" \
  && [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \
  && [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" \
# Install node.js long term support version to get npm
  && nvm install --lts \
# Install JSDoc to generate Javascript Documentation
  && npm install --location=global jsdoc
```

If I follow this with `RUN sh generate-documentation.sh`, the `docker build` command fails because it cannot find the command `jsdoc`, and if I follow it with `CMD sh generate-documentation.sh` the `docker compose up` command fails for the same reason.

I know that JSDoc has been installed correctly because I can attach the VSCode shell to the container and run `sh generate-documentation.sh` manually, the documentation is  generated as expected.

All the files are in the container's volume, so it can't be that there are project files missing.

Is there any reason that `jsdoc` cannot be found by commands in the dockerfile but can be found in the attached shell?

Comment: Your `export`s and `.` operations don't impact later RUN commands, only the current one. So the effect of `. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"` is finished after that `RUN` completes.

Comment: BTW, you don't need a backslash before `.`; there's no unwanted expansion that could happen and needs to be suppressed.